# What maven command "mvn clean install -e" does?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I know the what maven commnd `"mvn clean install"` does, but I have come across a new command `"mvn clean install -e"` can anyone have an idea about this ?

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=mvn+clean+install+-e

Comment: possible duplicate of [question on mvn -e clean install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033459/question-on-mvn-e-clean-install)

Answer (score 1):

To see what flags you can pass to `mvn` you can run:

```
mvn -h
```

which produces a lot of output, the relevant part for you is:

```
-e,--errors                            Produce execution error messages
```